# caching table values (avoiding unnecessary find queries) - is this a good approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app i often need to find brand id by brand name in many places, so what if...

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base

...

  after_save :refresh_names_hash

  #this is a rare action because brands list is static enough
  def refresh_names_hash
    Brand.names_hash(true)
  end

  def self.names_hash(refresh=false)
    @names_hash = nil if refresh
    @names_hash ||= Hash[all.map{|b| [b.name, b.id]}]
  end

...

end
```

Hope everything is clear enough from this code

And here is a question: is this a good approach to use `Brand.names_hash[params[:name]]` to achieve brand id every time i need it instead of query it from db in production environment (classes cache  enabled)?

Comment: Isn't ActiveRecord already using a cache and managing it for you? I would test the performance of this vs not having it to see if it actually makes things better.

Comment: `beg=Time.now;1000.times{Brand.find_by_id(rand(100))};dur=Time.now-beg;puts dur` => 2.390258
 vs 
`beg=Time.now;1000.times{Brand.names_hash[rand(100)]};dur=Time.now-beg;puts dur` >> 0.116661    ...  20 times faster